# Creating an custom API using existing API

Tags: node.js, web-services, express, tomcat

I am trying to set up a custom API for my application. This is a corporate application that I installed in my environment. The application comes with it's own out-of-the-box REST API, but I'm looking for a way to create my own custom API leveraging the existing one. The reason I want to create a custom API is because of all the customizations that have been made to the underlying database. I'm looking at using Node.js and the Express application framework to create the custom API, but all the use cases I've seen for this are for creating new APIs from scratch. I guess my question would be, how can I integrate my existing web services API into a Node.js (Express) set up. My existing web services API runs an Apache Tomcat web service. This publishes the existing web service endpoints in a format like this:

http://://?fields=,...

I'm looking for tips, pointers or something that can point me in the right direction. If there are any alternate (better) solutions available aside from Node.js (Express) I am open to exploring that as well.

Comment: Personally I don't see anything wrong with integrating another API into your own in order to suite your own needs. Most of the time this is done to create modules which can be included in other Node applications though. For example [the Google APIs on NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis)

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do. However, unless I'm missing something, I haven't found much documentation on how to integrate customizations made to an application into that application's already existing API. To be specific, I can already query endpoints and get a JSON formatted response in return. However, how would I set this up to leverage the existing web URL for my API to query and create elements for custom database tables? Something like this:

const express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get(/path/to/custom/endpoint, function(req, res) {
    res.send({})
})

Comment: I suppose it just depends on how extensive you are wanting to make it. If it is potentially going to be a very large API I would recommend setting up your own REST API using Node and Express like you said, but break apart like-routes into their own files. And of course, if you think a custom module for your API is necessary, then you can do that by creating your own functions using a dependency such as [request](https://github.com/request/request). Forgive me if i'm still not understanding the part where you want to leverage the existing URL.

Comment: Yeah, I think its probably me that doesn't fully understand it yet. I imagine it's probably a lot easier than I'm making it sound. I have Node.js installed on my machine and will download express and start playing around with it. I ran a few calls to the built-in REST API using Postman and it works. I just need to create wrapper resources around these calls to make it a uniform interface. Hopefully I'll be able to get this done in a few days.